# Time Complexity in a Given graph

Tags: graph, time-complexity, shortest-path

Given a directed acyclic graph with degree 'd' and length of shortest path between any 2 nodes is 'n', how much time is needed to find this path in terms of d and n?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a specific path between two node x and y:
it's O(d^n), as in any node, in the path, you have to 'take' up until d different pathes.
And you have to repeat this process up until n times.

Since it's exponential in n, this time analysis is only useful for very small n.
Mostly, you will prefer to look at this as running DFS on your graph, resulting in O(E+V) (this size of your graph)

Comment: I think we can see it as a tree with each node having atmost d children, then number of nodes would be d^n, and we would have to search these nodes , so time Complexity should be O(d^n). Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.